# How to run tests on Sepolia testnet in Foundry?

Tags: testing, solidity, forge

I know that it is possible to run tests on forked testnet in Foundry

```
forge test --fork-url SEPOLIA_RPC_URL
```

or

```
forge test --rpc-url SEPOLIA_RPC_URL #same result with --fork-url
```

But what if I want to run my tests on real sepolia testnet and actually pay sepolia eth for this tests? Is there a way in Foundry to do this (I know that in hardhat it is easily possible).

I have even this modifier in my tests that should only run on the real testnets:

```
modifier onlyOnDeployedContracts() {
      if (block.chainid == 31337) {
         return;
      }
      try vm.activeFork() returns (uint256) {
         return;
      } catch {
         _;
      }
   }
```

vm.activeFork should revert if there is no forking.